# A list being two positional arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to use a list as an argument in a class method, but it says that I give 2 arguments instead on one. I've made a prototype of my code and got the same error with it so it would be easier to grasp:

```
lol = ["lol1", "lol2", "lol3"]

class HasList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.li = []

    def setList(li):
        self.li = li


lolo = HasList()

lolo.setList(lol)
```

The error I get:
TypeError: setList() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)

Answer (score 6):

The first argument to a method in a class is always `self`.

```
def setList(self, li):
```

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting to pass in self as a parameter

```
def setList(self, li):
    self.li = li
```

Answer (score 3):

When you call `lolo.setList(lol)` what Python actually does is calling `setList(lolo,lol)`.

But `setList` has only one parameter `li` in your code, so the exception is raised:

```
def setList(li):
        self.li = li
```

Just add `self` as the first argument to `setList` so that is would be:

```
def setList(self,li):
        self.li = li
```